# Dropbear SSH Tunnel disconnected if upload a file

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, tunneling

i am newbie here.
I want to create ssh tunnel application,
but i have a problem with my application.
If I trying to upload a file (>500kb) trough that SSH Tunnel, my internet connection getting not responding and after that I'm disconnected from server.
what is the problem? do ssh server have a limit to upload connection?

***I use dropbear for ssh server**

Comment: no, i used local port forwarding and then upload the file with browser.

Comment: today, I tried with openSSHD Server, it's working fine. but why if i used dropbear, still getting disconnect while uploading.

Comment: To find dropbear problems, run it in the foreground rather than as background process. Use parameters "-F" (don't fork into background) and "-E" (log to standard error rather than syslog). You then might be able to see what happens to your session. But I have to admit that I also switched to OpenSSH in the end.